# Com Interop: Iterating Over Columns Instead Of Rows

Tags: excel, com-interop, excel-interop

I must be missing the painfully obvious but I can't figure out why this code is iterating across the columns of a row instead of down the rows of a column:

```
// ws = Excel worksheet
for (int i = 2; i <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Range range = ws.Cells[i][2];
    if (!range.Value2.ToString().Equals("Unknown"))
    {
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(range.Value2.ToString());
        if (count >= 3)
        {
            Range chronic = ws.Rows[i];
            chronic.EntireRow.Cells.Interior.Color = 0xFF0000;
        }
    }
}
```

This iterates across the columns of row 2 instead of down column 2 of all rows.  Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: @TimWilliams looks like an answer to me ... again :)

Answer (score 1):

`Cells[i][2]` should be `Cells[i,2]`